# bootstrap collapse visible only one at a time

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap [collapse](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse) that will show when click on the related button. the problem is this collapse does not work mutually. I want that only one collapse will be shown at a time and hide all others.

although the Accordion example is available it will not work on buttons. I am a newbie in bootstrap maybe I am doing in the wrong way.

this is my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/axtruo/5bh30r14/)

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExampleTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExampleTwo">
  Button with data-target
</button>

<div class="collapse" id="collapseExampleTwo">
  <div class="well">
      <div><p>2nd div</p></div>    
  </div>
</div>
```

how I show collapse only one at a time.

Comment: for your requirement go with Accordion, and style your accordion tabs accordingly.

Comment: is this is not possible with button ?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$('.btn-primary').on('click',function(){$('.collapse').collapse('hide');})
```